# System.ObjectDisposedException is thrown on performing ToList()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, graphql

Code where the error occurs: on ToList method the exemption is thrown

```
public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
   {
      var allProducts = _dbContext.Products.ToList();
      return allProducts;
   }
```

Product class:

```
   public class Product
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
```

GraphQL query:

```
 public class ProductQuery
    {
        private IProduct _productServices;

        public ProductQuery(IProduct productServices)
        {
            _productServices = productServices;
        }
        public List<Product> GetProducts() =>
            _productServices.GetAllProducts();

        public Product GetProductsById(int id) =>
            _productServices.GetProductById(id);
    }
```

Exemption:
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'GraphQLDbContext'.'

I believe this issue is not because of lazy loading as there are no dependency with other tables. I also have tried async await but i still get the exemption.

Adding start up for further detail.

```
using GraphQL_APIProject.Data;
using GraphQL_APIProject.Mutation;
using GraphQL_APIProject.Query;
using GraphqlProject.Interfaces;
using GraphqlProject.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GraphQL_APIProject
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddTransient<IProduct, ProductService>();
            services
            .AddGraphQLServer()
            .AddQueryType<ProductQuery>()
            .AddMutationType<ProductMutation>();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "GraphQL_APIProject", Version = "v1" });
            });
            services.AddDbContext<GraphQLDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-B0D3K2OQ; Initial Catalog = GraphQLDb; Integrated Security = true"));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, GraphQLDbContext dbContext)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "GraphQL_APIProject v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            //app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();


            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            //{
            //    endpoints.MapControllers();
            //});

            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            app
           .UseRouting()
           .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
           {
               endpoints.MapGraphQL();
           });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My first thought would be that you're creating a query via a context that is within a `using` but you're only running the query when the `using` is over and the context has been disposed

Comment: As you can see in the product query class and getproduct() method I have not used using keyword.